# MediaElement WinRT HUD information

Tags: windows-runtime

The winRT MediaElement integrates very nicely with the windows8 volume controls play and pause buttons.

I will like to display artist information also, I have the info how to I set it on the MediaElement?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

MediaElement is used to play audio or video. If you want to display anything else - you need to use some other controls overlaid on top of the MediaElement.

Comment: It also integrates with the Windows GUI so that from where I control the volumen I can pause/play and see the name of the app, I want to also see the name of the artist there and the track.

Comment: Oh, you mean in that overlay you get when you raise/decrease volume!

Comment: I don't know in that case. Perhaps the text info is taken automatically out of the file properties - like mp3 file ID3 tag...

Comment: I am streaming the file from a server, so I guess the ID3 tag is missing, I know a couple of apps in windows store that set that info for radio stations so there must be a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can set the artist name, track name & album artwork using the MediaControl class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediacontrol